# Finding pdfs with password security

Tags: pdf, automation

I have a directory with several hundred pdfs. I would like to find which among them have password security. Is there a way to do this faster than opening each one by one?

Comment: I believe the password protected ones, when viewed as plain text files, have a line saying `/Encrypt` near the end, which is missing from unprotected pdfs. So on Linux, you could use `grep -v`.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist: `fgrep -al '/Encrypt' *` worked perfectly. If you would like to submit that as an answer I would accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password protected ones, when viewed as plain text files, have a line saying "/Encrypt" near the end, which is missing from unprotected pdfs. So on Linux, you could use

```
$ fgrep -al '/Encrypt' *.pdf
```

to get a file list of the files containing "/Encrypt".

Note, the `-al` switches, which tell `fgrep` to (a) process all the files as if text files, and (l) list the names of the matching files without the matching lines, as well as (l) stop at first match in each file. See `man fgrep` for more details.